# rsync not copying files (just folder structure)

Tags: debian, rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using `rsync` on mounted volumes from a NAS box onto my Windows 10 laptop with WSL (Debian).  In the Debian shell, I mount the shared drive volumes and run `rsync` to make sure all of the source files (vol1) exist in the destination (vol2).

```
rsync -av --ignore-existing /mnt/vol1 /mnt/vol2
```

After running the command on the destination side I have a complete folder structure, but none of the files themselves were copied over.  I directed the results into a file and see that the files were included as part of the output, but they were not actually copied.  The same command works from my Mac terminal without issue, but I prefer working on my laptop so really want to be able to do this kind of storage management through WSL.

I think it is a permissions problem with Windows because I get failures on the WSL side:

rsync: mkstemp "filepath" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

Is there a fix for permissions on the WSL side when using SMB mounts?  I mount the volumes using

```
mount -t drvfs X: /mnt/s
```

Lastly, I do use sudo for the `rsync` command with the same result in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are running into a manifestation of [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3187#issuecomment-388904048).  To summarize, the destination drive is mounted as root, so you don't have permissions there.  The solution, as described there, is to simply `sudo mount -t drvfs X: /mnt/s -o uid=1000,gid=1000` (replacing the 1000 with your uid/gid if they are different).

In trying it myself without the mount options, I was able to reproduce your problem.  When I added the mount options to the destination drive, it worked correctly for me.